# QGIS - Reduce density uniformly

Tags: qgis, point

Is there anyway to reduce the density of point feature uniformly? I had tried the 'random extract' tool in QGIS but it will leave some pockets of empty areas like the image below which is not what I want.

[image]

Want a result where the distance between each points are more equally apart.
[image]

Comment: Can you show an illustration of what you want instead and name rules how it should be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can do an approach using clusters. With native QGIS processing tools you could do:

1. Run K-Means Clustering (or another clustering algorithm)
2. Run Minimum bounding geometry. Choose your clustered points as input, the cluster id as field and convex hull as geometry type
3. Run Centroids (or another suiting algorithm, for example point on surface, to build points) on these convex hulls

[image]